# EnvStats::epdfPlot() throws error with continuous distribution

Tags: r, envstats

I am trying to compute an empirical probability distribution for a continuous variable using the `epdfPlot()` function in the `EnvStats::` package.  I keep getting an error when I accept the default of `discrete=FALSE`.

```
Error in UseMethod("density") : 
  no applicable method for 'density' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Reading through the documentation, I think this is somehow a result of how the function passes arguments to `stats::density()` because I don't have this problem when I set `discrete = TRUE`.  As the documentation notes, the argument `density.arg.list=NULL` is ignored when `discrete = TRUE`.  Here is the reproducible example:

```
library(EnvStats)

dat<-rnorm(500, 0, 1)
demo1<-epdfPlot(dat, discrete = FALSE, plot.it=FALSE) # throws error
demo2<-epdfPlot(dat, discrete = TRUE, plot.it=FALSE) # works
demo2
```

Is this possibly a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this occurs because of a conflict with the `labdsv::density()` function.  `EnvStats::epdfPlot()` doesn't specify `stats::density()`, so when `density()` gets masked by another package, `EnvStats::epdfPlot()` calls that function.  I tried running the code in a different session and it worked without error.